# Apply elliptical border effect on the top only

Tags: css

Is it possible to have the elliptical effect for the top only?

From this site, https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-radius/, I wanted to copy the effect done with '/'.

```
border-radius: 30px/10px;
```

Except I can't make the effect apply to the top right and left only. Is this possible using border-radius?

```css
.border-radius {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: tomato;
  border-radius: 30px/10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="border-radius"></div>
```

Comment: Your title says "top only", but your question says "top right and bottom only". Which is it?

Comment: Sorry, was in a hurry. Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I apply the effect to the top right and bottom only

According to the [Borders Module Level 3 - Border-radius](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-radius), the shorthand syntax is:

```
[ <length> | <percentage> ]{1,4} [ / [ <length> | <percentage> ]{1,4} ]?
```

The order of the values is top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left. Therefore if you only want to apply it to the top-right and bottom, you can use a value of `0 30px 30px 30px/0 10px 10px 10px`.

You could also just set a border-radius of `30px/10px` on all the sides, and then override the top-left:

```
border-radius: 30px/10px;
border-top-left-radius: 0;
```

```css
.border-radius {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: tomato;
  border-radius: 0 30px 30px 30px/0 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="border-radius"></div>
```

Likewise, a value of `30px 30px 0 0/10px 10px 0 0` would only apply to the top:

```css
.border-radius {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: tomato;
  border-radius: 30px 30px 0 0/10px 10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="border-radius"></div>
```

Comment: ah I didn't realize it can be extracted that way. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sure, why not? `border-radius` can be defined for each corner;
More info - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #F72F4E;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.Box {
  width: 50vmin;
  height: 50vmin;
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Box"></div>
```

Comment: You have to do `border-top-left-radius: 30px 10px;  border-top-right-radius: 30px 10px;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `border-top-right-radius` and `border-bottom-right-radius`:

```
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: red;
border-top-right-radius: 20px 50px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 20px 50px;
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jacquesc/L1zz0an3/2/